# complete scan windows to find any issues and fix them

Tags: windows, command-line, scanner

I remember there was a phrase we type in **'Run box'**/ **command-line** and insert windows CD in drive, then it scans whole system for probable errors and fix them. Would you please say it?

Or Any new similar concept maybe exists.

Comment: There was `sfc /scannow`, but it does *not* check for "probable errors", only for corrupted system files (which is somewhat rare).

Comment: SFC checks for corrupted, missing or the wrong versions of system files, its a pretty comprehensive scan.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any command to scan registry too?
also where is the reference for these commands?

Comment: The registry is somewhat like a journalled filesystem: the hives don't get corrupted; if they do, they are repaired automatically. The *data*, however, cannot be checked since Windows doesn't *know* what is "correct" and what is "wrong".

Comment: @grawity If the registry repaired automatically, so for What is these huge number of registry checker/booster applications? Thanks

Comment: @1Geeky: Keep in mind that data and internal structure are two separate things -- just like files on a filesystem. The filesystem structure can be repaired automatically, but if the data is corrupt only its creator can know it... If you have a folder full of music, it won't slow the computer down just by *being* there, and neither will a registry key... There *are* some cases when "registry cleaners" can be useful (e.g. stale pointers to old DLLs) but they very rarely fix actual *issues*, at least from my own experience.

Comment: @grawity Ok. So you mean stockpile of registry keys over the time doesn't affect system performance caused just by being those keys over and over each other in the registry? Did I understand true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be thinking of [System File Checker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_File_Checker)

.

[SFC in XP](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/system_file_checker.mspx?mfr=true)

[Vista and W7](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833)

SFC in XP can be problematic since it uses an installation CD to source its files if they are needed, and these may be the incorrect versions since windows updates can change system file versions, you should at least use a XP install disc that is the same Service Pack version as the XP system you are running SFC on.

Vista and W7 does not suffer from this problem, it sources the files from your current installation cache of files.